# j_security_check only works on fresh page

Tags: java, jsp, security, jboss, jaas

We have a `j_security` login form that only works on a fresh page. Meaning no history, no previous logins and no failed logins. If the page is fresh and a user enters a wrong password, the proper error appears. But when the user enters the correct password there after, an `HTTP Status 400 -  Invalid direct reference to form login page` appears and logins are suspended until the browser's history is cleared and the page is reloaded.

[image: HTTP 400]

Here is the code for the login. The `Dropdown.getXML` changes the url depending on development environment. In this case it changes it to development which is correct.

```
<form id="login" name="j_security_form" action="<%out.write(Dropdown.getXML("https://www.example.com/public/j_security_check")); %>" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <strong>Account Login</strong><br>
                Username:<br>
                    <input type="text" name="j_username"><br>
                Password:<br>
                    <input type="password" name="j_password"><br>
                <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login"><br>
                <br>
                    New users <a href="../user_registration.jsp">register here</a><br>
                    <a href="../forgot_password.jsp">Forgot password?</a>
                    <input type="hidden" name="auth_mode" value="basic">        
                <script>
                var newloc = document.location.href;
                newloc =newloc.replace('index.jsp','index.jsp');
                document.write('<input type="hidden" name="orig_url" value="'+newloc+'">');
                </script>
        </form>
```

Please help us find the answer to this problem! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to directly access the page that you specified as your login page in the `web.xml`. This login page is a special page to which the user will be redirected when he tries to access a secure resource and he isn't logged in yet.

If you need direct access to a login page or display a login form in an unprotected page, you can implement a programatic login in a servlet, manage bean (jsf), etc.

[Using Programmatic Security with Web Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjiie.html)